# NSNotificationCenter Add?

Tags: xcode, ios4, nsnotificationcenter

I have two view that when you switch from one to another, they call a notification to the view that's about to get loaded to refresh the content. The weird thing is that the first time the view loads, it will call it once, the next time twice, and so on. I concluded that it's because they keep getting added every time the view loads. Since the dealloc never get's called it's still there and it will keep adding now.

So is there a way to check if the notification exists before getting added to fix this issue?

Here's what I have in my viewDidLoad

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ReloadGridNotification:) name:@"ReloadOHGridView" object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ReloadBadgeNotification:) name:@"reloadBadge" object:nil];
```

And my dealloc:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Thanks!
Coulton

**EDIT 1:**

I show my views in a UINavigationController and switch between them. Here's my code to refresh the different view:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadBadge" object:self];
}
```

Comment: How are you loading, and showing, your views?

Comment: Please post the code where you're actually creating and showing the views. I sense a bizarre setup, but it's hard to understand without the actual code.

Comment: @magma: I'm pretty sure it's correct. I removed my observer in my viewWillUnload, and it only gets called once. But I can't put it there because I want to call it again.

Comment: my fault - I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call addObserver, the notification center will add a entry to its internal structures. This means the notification center will call your observer once more every time you call viewDidLoad.

If your view is unloaded for any reason and then reloaded, then viewDidLoad will get called again. Your removeobserver will not get called until the object is destroyed, which may explain why your removeobserver did not work.

You should either check whether you have already called addObserver with a flag, or manually remove the observer with removeObserver when you unload your view in the viewDidUnload method.

Edit1: Alternatively, can you add the observers somewhere else, like in the App Delegate?

Comment: I have tried that and nothing has worked. And I have tried calling it in my viewWillUnload, and it works but I can't call it again.

Comment: What do you mean 'can't call it again'?

Comment: If I put `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` in my viewWillUnload it will work and only get called once even after switching through the views. However, I can never call my notification to do whatever I have set up. Here's how I call it: `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadBadge" object:self];`. Thanks, Coulton!

Comment: I suggest you put the addobserver in some other place, like in the app delegate or the view's init function, since you really only need to call addobserver once anyway.

Comment: Moving all my NSNotification observers would be a true pain with over 10 items and very long, confusing code that would have to be transfered over...

Comment: @futureelite7: Also, How do I "check whether you have already called addObserver with a flag"? Thanks

Comment: just use a boolean and set it after you have added the observer. Clear the boolean if you remove the observer.

Answer (score 0):

When memory gets tight the OS will dump your view, but will first call `viewDidUnload`; when it has to reload them it calls `viewDidLoad`. `dealloc`, however, is only called when all references to your view have been released, which likely doesn't happen until your app quits.

As a result, as @futureelite7 noted, you're adding a new observer every time your view is reloaded but, effectively, are never removing it.

All you need to do is ensure that the observer is added in `viewDidLoad` and removed in `viewDidUnload` you won't have the multiple notification problem. No need for a flag or for putting the observer anywhere else.

From your comments it sounds like you might have tried it, but I suggest going through your code and making absolutely certain you're only adding them in DidLoad and are always removing them in DidUnload. It works like a charm in app after app.

---

**Edited to Add**

Because your view keeps getting unloaded, which only happens if you do it manually, if all references to it are lost, or if memory gets tight, I suggest looking at all three to help ensure you're doing what you can to keep your view around.

Comment: I have to be able to call to update at anytime to this view. But if the observer is removed, it won't work.

Comment: Your problem isn't that the observer is removed -- when used properly as I've described you have one observer and no duplicates -- it's that your view is being inconveniently unloaded. I suggested several things at the end of my answer: have you checked any of them?

Comment: I tried putting it in my viewWillAppear, rather my viewDidLoad, and it doesn't get added and nothing happens when I try to call the notification. I also removed it in my viewDidUnload, and it doesn't remove it. Everytime I load it again, I have the same issues. Please note I am using a UINavigation Controller. Thanks.

Comment: If you've examined whether you're (a) releasing your view inappropriately, (b) allowing your view to be released inappropriately, or (c) inappropriately loading up your other view with memory trouble and there's no way to stop the other view from unloading, then an alternate solution is in order, but you really should check those things first.

Comment: Your nav controller has nothing to do with it. Rather than randomly moving the calls around, have you looked at the things I suggested?

Comment: I did what you are saying the the third paragraph and It doesn't even call the viewWillLoad (but the viewDidLoad is). How do I check if my view is inapropratly displayed? Here's how I switch views: `DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
dvController = nil;
[dvController release];`

Comment: Looks like you're holding onto it. (BTW, I had a mistake in my original post, meant `viewDidLoad` and not `viewWillLoad`.) That leaves the question of memory: what are you doing in the second view? Have you run Instruments to look for leaks?

Comment: No, I haven't what tools do I need to run and how to run them?

Comment: I have noticed that my `viewDidUnload` never gets called after you go BACK in the UINavigationController. But when you go back to it, it calls the `viewDidLoad` and it adds another observer.

Comment: viewDidUnload shouldn't be called by the viewController you're navigating back to, that's expected. Navigating back doesn't call viewDidLoad either: the view will be loaded if it's not already loaded, which may or may not be the case when navigating to it. That you're still getting multiple observers despite *only* adding them in viewDidLoad and *only and always* removing them in viewDidUnload -- you're absolutely certain that's the case, right? -- says that there's something messed up at a basic level. Try a breakpoint in viewDidLoad to see where and when it's called.

Comment: Here's a good tutorial on using Instruments to track memory leaks: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial